# Envato Theme check plugin shows warning about add_meta_box

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, meta-boxes

I am working on a wordpress theme and get this warning after theme check in envato theme check plugin. Actually im not getting the exact issue behind this warning and how to resolve this so please help me to resolve this issue.

```
WARNING: Found add_meta_box in the file framework/page-options/general.php. Custom meta box functions are allowed for design only. Ensure this is a valid use case.
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding meta boxes directly to the theme it's not allowed, I suggest you create a core plugin for meta boxes of that theme and include it from the TGMPA.

Check the latest requirements from Envato about the WordPress Themes: [external link](https://forums.envato.com/t/updated-wordpress-requirements/173223)

Comment: okk But i`m using dynamic featured images plugin in my theme and get same warning from plugin files so how can manage this now?? WARNING: Found add_meta_box in the file wp-content/themes/theme-name/framework/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/dynamic-featured-image.php. Custom meta box functions are allowed for design only. Ensure this is a valid use case.

Line 124: add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'initialize_featured_box' ) );